# Extracting DevOps Data Programmatically?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am to extract data from DevOps programmatically ie. write a program that can access all attributes of any Epic, Issue, or Task for a RestAPI. However, everything I've  tried so far and found on the internet for this purpose have not been working so far.

[This is where the tab for time allotment is supposed to be placed under any issue/task/epic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqJLH.png)

It seems to me, that it is possible to retrieve the data, and someone must have done it before. I just don't think it's been properly documented online anywhere. (This is your chance!)

**End-goal:**
*To put in the amount of time spent on any task/Epic/Issue in a board and have it update in our proprietary company software.*

I have already tried to follow [Microsoft's own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/quickstarts/work-item-quickstart?view=azure-devops) method but without any luck.

Does anyone have any idea?

I'd love for it to be preferably C# as this is what our current implementation with Jira uses.